# ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got CHAR from case expression

Tags: sql, oracle, char, numbers, case

I'm trying a case expression:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN CAB.CODTIPOPER IN (3200, 3201, 3210) 
            THEN CAB.NUMNOTA
        WHEN CAB.CODTIPOPER IN (3100, 3106) 
            THEN (SELECT DISTINCT GET_NFES(VAR.NUNOTAORIG) 
                  FROM TGFVAR VAR 
                  WHERE VAR.NUNOTAORIG = CAB.NUNOTA) 
        ELSE NULL
    END AS "NUM_NF"
--this select inside the parenthesis is a sql typed per the ERP devs
```

But I get this error:

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got CHAR

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, what data type is `CAB.NUMNOTA`, and what data type does your `GET_NFES` function return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your error is:

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got CHAR
```

Then:

- `CAB.NUMNOTA` is a `NUMBER` data type and
- `GET_NFES(VAR.NUNOTAORIG)` returns a string data type.

You need to convert them to be the same data type by either using `TO_CHAR(CAB.NUMNOTA)` or `TO_NUMBER(GET_NFES(VAR.NUNOTAORIG))`.

So either:

```sql
SELECT CASE
       WHEN CAB.CODTIPOPER IN (3200, 3201, 3210) 
       THEN TO_CHAR(CAB.NUMNOTA)
       WHEN CAB.CODTIPOPER IN (3100, 3106) 
       THEN (SELECT DISTINCT
                    GET_NFES(VAR.NUNOTAORIG) 
             FROM   TGFVAR VAR 
             WHERE  VAR.NUNOTAORIG = CAB.NUNOTA) 
       ELSE NULL
       END AS "NUM_NF"
```

or:

```sql
SELECT CASE
       WHEN CAB.CODTIPOPER IN (3200, 3201, 3210) 
       THEN CAB.NUMNOTA
       WHEN CAB.CODTIPOPER IN (3100, 3106) 
       THEN (SELECT DISTINCT
                    TO_NUMBER(GET_NFES(VAR.NUNOTAORIG))
             FROM   TGFVAR VAR 
             WHERE  VAR.NUNOTAORIG = CAB.NUNOTA) 
       ELSE NULL
       END AS "NUM_NF"
```

*(Note: if `GET_NFES(VAR.NUNOTAORIG)` does not return a string containing a number then trying to convert it to a number will fail so its more likely that the you want the first option over the second.)*

*(Note 2: you may then get further errors if the sub-query returns more than one row.)*

Answer (score 0):

The cause is certainly that the GET_NFES() is returning VARCHAR result while the NUMNOTA is a NUMBER. You can fix the types with a TO_NUMBER(), however this SELECT DISTINCT ... just triggers me since places where you can get more than one row as a result in a CASE just looks wrong.